# Awaiting first stream event as a future?

Tags: dart

I am setting up a stream and would like to return the first value as a Future.

I would like to do this because the first value is needed to render some components, but it will continue to update the components afterwards.

How can one achieve this in dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use a broadcasting stream which can have multiple listeners and be closed/opened multiple times.

```
StreamController controller = StreamController.broadcast();
controller.add(foo);

controller.listen((var e) {
    print('new event $e');
});

controller.first.then((var e) {
    print('first event $e');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myStream.first
```

does return a `Future` with the first value

**update**

according to the comments below

```
var isFirst = true;
var completer = new Completer<Object>();
myStream.listen((event) {
  if(isFirst) {
    isFirst = false;
    completer.complete(event);
  } 
  setState(() => foo = event);
});
return completer.future;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I have run into a problem with this approach. If use `myStream.first` I cannot listen to the stream afterwords. This seems to turn a stream into a future, not complete a future on the first event. Any insight? :)

Comment: "This seems to turn a stream into a future, not complete a future on the first event. Any insight?" I don't know what this sentence means. I'll update my answer with another example that might do what you want.

Comment: What I mean is this: If myStream.first does not allow any listeners to be attached afterwards, than it has effectively turned the stream into a future that only returns the first event. Right?

Comment: I don't think `myStream.first` works for me. I'm trying to create a stream and return a future when it gets its first event. But I need to be able to use it as a stream afterwards as well.

Comment: Thank you! I just saw it. Much appreciated.